# Multilevel dropdown buttons Flutter - State and city

Tags: flutter

I have 2 levels of list selection. At the moment, a list is displayed, but I need to bind id to cities.

I can't find the example I want. Could you tell me how to do this?
If there is a living example, I would be grateful, since I do not have experience in flutter yet.

```
List<String> countries = ['USA', 'India'];
  List<String> indiaProvince = ['New Delhi', 'Bihar', 'Rajasthan'];
  List<String> usaProvince = ['Texas', 'Florida', 'California'];

  List<String> provinces = [];
  String selectedCountry;
  String selectedProvince;  // will ues this variable later

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Multi Level Dropdown'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          hint: Text('Country'),
          value: selectedCountry,
          items: countries.map((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: onChangedCallback,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onChangedCallback(country) {
    if (country == 'USA') {
      provinces = usaProvince;
    } else if (country == 'India') {
      provinces = indiaProvince;
    } else {
      provinces = [];
    }
    setState(() {
      selectedProvince = null;
      selectedCountry = country;
    });
  }
```

I found something similar, but I don’t know how to display it correctly.

```
   int id;
   String name;
   List<City> cities;
}

    class City {
   int id;
   String name;
}
```

Comment: you are trying to get provinces  according to country that is selected right?

Comment: @Diwyansh yes. and I need an id for each city. To add to the database.